# Was footage released of the Soyuz TMA-20M crew arrival ceremony?

Tags: crewed-spaceflight, soyuz-spacecraft

I couldn't find a YouTube video of the welcome ceremony of the newly arrived crew of Soyuz TMA-20M.

Was there no broadcast on NASA TV of this event?

Comment: Is this not what your looking for? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cDCvwvhbqBg

Comment: Unfortunately not; it should be the analogue of youtube.com/watch?v=lJJExh5U77c

Comment: If you skip to 5:11 you can see the hatch opening, are you sure there was an actual cerenomy? Because I don't think there was one due to the time in Baikonur. It was a night launch (21:26:38 UTC) and the docking with the ISS was at 03:09 UTC which meant in Kazakhstan it would have been 9 o'clock in the morning (UTC+6).

Comment: Here is a very brief excerpt at the end of the video of this ceremony youtube.com/watch?v=eP4kuYXpJPE

Comment: @ray Is this what you are looking for? http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x3zh9jo

Answer (score 3):

The video of the welcome ceremony for Expedition 47, the crew of the Soyuz TMA-20M, was in fact released publicly. I found one copy of it on Daily Motion:

[Expedition 47 Welcome Ceremony](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x3zh9jo)

The footage does contain the hatch opening as well and is a little over 18 minutes long, so you may want to grab some popcorn.